# Login failed for user 'Domain\UserID'. Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

What do i need to do for this error...Neither windows auth not sql server auth works.

Following is the entry in the SQL Server log:

2013-08-08 13:37:55.70 Logon       Login failed for user 'Domain\UserID'. Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided. [CLIENT: local machine]
2013-08-08 13:39:20.73 Logon       Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 5.

thanks!!!

Answer (score 10):

Did you add that windows login in SQL Server?

```
CREATE LOGIN [<domainName>\<login_name>] FROM WINDOWS;
GO
```

Update:

If you do not know the sa password and your windows login does not work.  You will have to do one of the following:

- Unistall and reinstall
- Put the instance in single user mode (only works if you are an admin on the SQL Server machine), http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207004.aspx

Comment: I cant get to the SQL Server Query window where i can run the CREATE because of the login faliure...how do i get there.....

Comment: Which login did you add when you installed? There should be a login that was created or you can use the sa login.

Comment: It was installed by the helpdesk and they don't remember what they did. I asked - but they said - here is the CD, uninstall and and then install in back again. My windows network password does not log me in via windows authentication......Also not sure what the sa password would be? I tried logging in as user id "sa" and blank password but the login fails....I am using Sql server 2012.

Comment: unfortunately, you have two options.  1) reinstall as recommended by your helpdesk. 2).  If you are an administrator on the computer where the SQL instance is installed.  You can put the instance into administrative mode and add your login and give it permissions.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207004.aspx.

Comment: No need to reinstall. Just follow my solution below: restart srv in single user mode and add your user to the logins. That's it. I don't know why SO or the whole internet doesn't have this laid down as needed.

Comment: I had a wasted a lot of time trying resolve this issue for me, but doing these steps I can fix it, thank you!

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77921718/2218697) post to **fix windows authentication mode doesn't work.**

Answer (score 5):

I had same problem too. I tried many solutions but none worked for me. I'm sure that I have set sa password and I was trying with this password - didn't work. Windows users also didn't work.
Finally,  I tried sa with no password , it worked.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77921718/2218697) post to **fix windows authentication mode doesn't work.**

Answer (score 3):

1. Restart SQL Server in single user mode. That is part of these steps (adding `-m` to Start Parameters): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207004.aspx
2. start `sqlcmd` from an admin command line (`cmd` started as an Adminstrator). Do not start `SSMS`, otherwise that can take up the single user slot.
3. On the `sqlcmd` prompt say

   ```
   sp_addsrvrolemember 'Domain\UserID', 'sysadmin'
   GO
   quit
   ```

Now you added your local user to the SQL server logins, and that user has the sysadmin role as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think the help desk should have a local administrator account if you do not.  Have then follow the MSDN article that Adam posted if you do not have admin rights.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error. Disabling CEIP from [SQL Server Error and Usage Reporting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/sql/virtual-machines-windows-sql-server-iaas-overview?toc=%2Fazure%2Fvirtual-machines%2Fwindows%2Ftoc.json#customer-experience-improvement-program-ceip)  resolved the issue for me.