# Login to Microsoft SQL Server Error: 18456

Tags: sql-server, connection, error-code

I am getting this error while trying to connect to the SQL Server.

> Microsoft SQL Server Error: 18456

Can anybody tell me what the error code means?

Comment: A cursory search seems to indicate that the error code is a login failure, and is generally accompanied by more detailed information.

Comment: And that more detailed info should be in the sql server error log. The number itself deliberately doesn't tell you much, so crackers can't use it for clues on where their attempts are going wrong.

Comment: useful information found [here](https://sqlblog.org/2011/01/14/troubleshooting-error-18456)

Comment: I just had to `run as administrator`

Answer (score 851, accepted):

If you're trying to connect using "SQL Server Authentication" then you may want to modify your server authentication:

Within the Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, in the Object Explorer window:

1. Right-click on the server and click **Properties**
2. Go to the **Security** page
3. Under **Server authentication**, choose the **SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode** radio button
4. Click **OK**
5. Restart SQL Services

Comment: In addition to the steps above, I had to create a SQL connection user account. Windows Active Directory user accounts cannot connect through the SQL connection method. 

From MS SQL Server Mgmt Studio:
1. Expand Security
2. Right Click on Logins
3. Select New Login...
4. Check the radio button for SQL Server authentication. 
5. Follow the remaining prompts.

Comment: @JGilmartin,
How exactly will you be able to connect to the server in the Object Explorer when you have the Error 18456 which mean you *can not connect*??

Comment: Thanks! In addition to this, I had to go to `SQL Server Configuration Manager` / `SQL Server Network Configuration` \ `Protocols for SQLEXPRESS`. And there enable both `Named Pipes` and `TCP/IP`.

Comment: ... and then I had to set 1433 port manually like here https://stackoverflow.com/a/24299346/3886961

Comment: @Shai Alon For those who can't actually connect to the server in object explorer, try running SSMS as Administrator.

Answer (score 79):

Check out [this MSDN blog article](http://web.archive.org/web/20151130050158/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2006/02/21/536201.aspx) from the data platform team.

You need to look at the state part of the error message to find the root cause of the issue.

```
2, 5 = Invalid userid
6 = Attempt to use a Windows login name with SQL Authentication
7 = Login disabled and password mismatch
8 = Password mismatch
9 = Invalid password
11, 12 = Valid login but server access failure
13 = SQL Server service paused
18 = Change password required
```

Comment: Not to toot my own horn, but I have compiled a *lot* more information here: https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/01/14/sql-server-v-next-denali-additional-states-for-error-18456.aspx

Comment: You always toot you horn ...  Thanks for the up-vote?  But you list does seem to be more complete!  I think most people do not know how to use Google.

Comment: I was tempted to up-vote, however I'm torn because answering questions that could be answered by Google just encourages people to keep asking here instead of searching...

Comment: 99% of questions here could probably be answered by Google however a plain simple question and answer saves considerable amount of search time and pouring over often superfluous articles/blogs, and  so one up vote from me!

Comment: HERE is where I find the answers when I use google (google searches SO better than SO searches SO...)

Comment: If you came here because you received this error code from `tsql` command for linux, be warned that the `State 1` message will be the only state reported.  The actual cause listed in the answer above is only viewable from the side of the SQL server.

Comment: You guys do realize the very existence of this stuff is what enables google to give you the answer.....

Comment: Just for completeness, I had a state of 1, which is not included in this table.  I solved my problem by enabling Windows and SQL Server authentication as stated in [http://stackoverflow.com/a/23395581/2856659](above)...

Comment: For me the state is 1, which isn't on your list.

Comment: if you get error state 1, you should restart SQL service. just click on server name and hit Restart!! (or restart from services)

Comment: I'd like to know why error state 65 is in Aaron Bertrand's (awesome) blog but apparently not in any official MS doco that I can find

Comment: thanks @AaronBertrand for the info. the page has been moved: https://sqlblog.org/2020/07/28/troubleshooting-error-18456

Answer (score 38):

Before opening, right-click and choose 'Run as Administrator'. This solved the problem for me.

Comment: this was the fix for me.  I had `State: 1` in the error message.

Comment: Before opening what??

Comment: I'm assuming they are referring to SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)

Answer (score 20):

I have faced this issue.

Please look at the attached image,

Step 1: Go to server property

Step 2: Go to Security

Step 3: Change server authentication as SQL server and WindowsAuthenication mode

and restart your Sql server.

[image]

Answer (score 11):

first see the details of the error 
if "state" is "1"
Ensure the database is set for both SQL and Windows authentication under SQL server / Properties / Security.

for other state see the above answers ....

Comment: OMG thank you! None of my logins were working, then I stumbled across this answer and found that somehow my SQL Express instance got changed from "SQL and Windows authentication" to "Windows authentication". Changed it back and all works.

Comment: Also, closing SSMS in not enough, a restart to the SqlServer service is required for the change to take affect.

Answer (score 11):

**Just an update, here is the solution if anyone else has there error with a properly configured login:**

If you're trying to connect using "SQL Server Authentication" then you may want to modify your server authentication:

Within the Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio in the object explorer:

Right click on the server and click Properties

Go to the Security page

Under Server authentication choose the SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode radio button

Click OK

Restart SQL Services

Comment: This was my fix, thank you! It was a new SQLExpress server.

Answer (score 9):

1. Check whether mixed mode authentication is enabled in you server->properties
2. Then create a login in the server->security
3. create an user for that login in your database
4. Then restart your server by right clicking the instance and select restart

In addition, check and enable TCP/IP and Named Pipes
[SQL Server Configuration Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atd54.png)

"Security > Logins > [LoginUser] > Properties Select a page > Securables"

[Server name and Connect SQL > Grant](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FP3Ub.png)

Add TSQL Default TCP and TSQL Named Pipes endpoints by
"Security >Logins >[LoginUser] >Properties Select a page >Securables
Search >Specific Objects >Endpoint >Object Types >Endpoints >Check > Ok >Browse >Ok >Ok"

[Endpoints >](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJL0X.png)

"Select Endpoint > Connect > Grant > Ok"

[TSQL Default TCP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NecM2.png)
[TSQL Named Pipes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jayv.png)

Try to log in again.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 9):

If you change a login user credential or add new login user then after you need to log in then you will have to restart the SQL Server Service. for that

GO to--> Services
[image: gray color row]

Then go to SQL Server(MSSQLSERVER) and stop and start again

Now try to log in, I hope You can.

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Just happened to me, and turned out to be different than all other cases listed here.

I happen to have two virtual servers hosted in the same cluster, each with it own IP address. The host configured one of the servers to be the SQL Server, and the other to be the Web server. However, SQL Server is installed and running on both. The host forgot to mention which of the servers is the SQL and which is the Web, so I just assumed the first is Web, second is SQL.

When I connected to the (what I thought is) SQL Server and tried to connect via SSMS, choosing Windows Authentication, I got the error mentioned in this question. After pulling lots of hairs, I went over all the setting, including SQL Server Network Configuration, Protocols for MSSQLSERVER:

> [image: screenshot of TCP/IP configuration]

Double clicking the TCP/IP gave me this:

> [image: TCP/IP properties, showing wrong IP address]

The IP address was of the other virtual server! This finally made me realize I simply confused between the servers, and all worked well on the second server.

Answer (score 5):

Also you can just login with windows authentication and run the following query to enable it:

```
ALTER LOGIN sa ENABLE ;  
GO  
ALTER LOGIN sa WITH PASSWORD = '<enterStrongPasswordHere>' ;  
GO
```

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/change-server-authentication-mode

Answer (score 3):

Right Click the User, go to properties, change the default database to master
This is the screen print of the image which shows what you have to check if you have the error 19456. Sometimes it default to a database which the user doesn't have permission

Answer (score 3):

18456 Error State List

ERROR STATE ERROR DESCRIPTION

- State 2 and State 5 Invalid userid
- State 6 Attempt to use a Windows login name with SQL Authentication
- State 7 Login disabled and password mismatch
- State 8 Password mismatch
- State 9 Invalid password
- State 11 and State 12     Valid login but server access failure
- State 13 SQL Server service paused
- State 18 Change password required

Potential causes
Below is a list of reasons and some brief explanation what to do:

**SQL Authentication not enabled**: If you use SQL Login for the first time on SQL Server instance than very often error 18456 occurs because server might be set in Windows Authentication mode (only).

*How to fix*? Check this [SQL Server and Windows Authentication Mode page.](https://katieandemil.academy/error-18456-sql-server-and-windows-authentication-mode)

**Invalid userID:** SQL Server is not able to find the specified UserID on the server you are trying to get. The most common cause is that this userID hasn’t been granted access on the server but this could be also a simple typo or you accidentally are trying to connect to different server (Typical if you use more than one server)

**Invalid password:** Wrong password or just a typo. Remember that this username can have different passwords on different servers.

**less common errors:** The userID might be disabled on the server. Windows login was provided for SQL Authentication (change to Windows Authentication. If you use SSMS you might have to run as different user to use this option). Password might have expired and probably several other reasons…. If you know of any other ones let me know.

**18456 state 1 explanations:** Usually Microsoft SQL Server will give you error state 1 which actually does not mean anything apart from that you have 18456 error. State 1 is used to hide actual state in order to protect the system, which to me makes sense. Below is a list with all different states and for more information about retrieving accurate states visit [Understanding "login failed" (Error 18456) error messages in SQL Server 2005](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2006/02/21/536201.aspx)

Hope that helps

Answer (score 2):

For me, it was **wrong** login and password.

Answer (score 2):

First go to start bar then search local services
Then click on "view local services" 
Then it will open service window then go to SQL Server(MSSQLSERVER) right click on it and click on stop and then again right click on it and click start. Now you can able to login and put your user name as 'sa' and password is your won password.

Answer (score 1):

Please check to see if you are connected to the network if this is a domain member PC. Also, make sure you are not on a dual home PC as your routes may be incorrect due to network metrics. I had this issue when I could not connect to the domain the SQL windows authentication switched to the local PC account but registered it as a SQL authentication. Once I disabled my wireless adapter and rebooted, the Windows integration switched back to the domain account and authenticated fine. I had already set up Mixed mode as you had already done as well so the previous posts do not apply.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this can happen if you are trying to log in with a user that is defined in Active Directory, but attempt using "SQL Server Authentication" in the login screen. I do not know how to specify a different user with NTLM/Windows Authentication: When I click the Windows Authentication dropdown, the username and password is blanked out, and I can only log in as myself.

Answer (score 0):

In my case multiple wrong attempts locked the account.To do that I had tried running the below query and it worked:
ALTER LOGIN  WITH PASSWORD= UNLOCK
And make sure to set the option "Enforce Password Security" option for specific user to be unchecked by right click on Sql Server -> Properties.

Answer (score 0):

## SQL Server connection troubleshoot

In case you are not able to connect with SQL Authentication and you've tried the other solutions.

You may try the following:

### Check connectivity

- Disable Firewall.
- Run PortQry on 1434 and check the answer.

### Check the state

- Try to connect with SSMS or sqlcmd and check the message.
- State 1 is rarely documented but it just mean you don't have the right to know the true state.
- Look at the log file in the directory of SQL server to know what is the state.

## The State 5

What ? my login doesn't exist ? it's right there, I can see it in SSMS. How can it be ?

> The most likely explanation is the most likely to be the right one.

### The state of the login

- Destroy, recreate it, enable it.
- reset the password.

Or...

*"You don't look at the right place" or "what you see is not what you think".*

#### The Local DB and SQLEXPRESS conflict

If you connect with SSMS with Windows authentication, and your instance is named SQLEXPRESS, you are probably looking at the **LocalDb** and *not the right server*. So you just created your login on LocalDb.

When you connect through SQL Server authentication with SSMS, it will try to connect to SQLEXPRESS real server where your beloved login doesn't exist yet.

***Additional note:*** Check in the connection parameters tab if you've not forgotten some strange connection string there.

Answer (score 0):

Another **worked** solution for me.
`serever->security->logins->new logins->General->`create your user name as login name,Click sql server authentication add passwords

uncheck the password verification three  checkboxes .
This will work.

Remeber to change the server properties ->Security from `Server authentication` to `SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode`

Answer (score 0):

you can do in linux for mssql
   change password for sa account

**sudo /opt/mssql/bin/mssql-conf setup**

```
The license terms for this product can be downloaded from
 http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=746388 Jump Jump
and found in /usr/share/doc/mssql-server/LICENSE.TXT.
Do you accept the license terms? [Yes/No]:yes
  Setting up Microsoft SQL Server
Enter the new SQL Server system administrator password:  --Enter strong password
Confirm the new SQL Server system administrator password: --Enter strong password
 starting Microsoft SQL Server...
 Enabling Microsoft SQL Server to run at boot...
Setup completed successfully.
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error after creating a new sysadmin user under my SQL instance. 
My admin user was created under a specific domain
**MyOrganization/useradmin**

Using **useradmin** on a disconnected environment allows you to create other users using SQL Server authentication, but as soon as you try to login you get

> Microsoft SQL Server Error: 18456

To fix the problem, try to connect again to your Organization network and create the user while you are connected and then you can get disconnected and will work.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue. In case you see it, run this query:

```sql
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE

DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS
```

then it shows a 18456 error code.

Do one thing again run same query after reconnecting SQL server. It will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Click on "Options" and under "Connection Properties" specify the catalog/database name next to "Connect to database:". I got the error because this was set to <default> and I needed to specify the dbname.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18456
I was getting an issue because I was entering the wrong password.
Microsoft SQL Server, Error code: 18456 - This indicates that the password is incorrect.

**Reference**: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-18456-database-engine-error?view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score 0):

it happen with me when I have restored my computer

enable windows and sql authentication
reboot your PC

in vs code in my case still in error because i forget install pyodbc :D

Answer (score 0):

When I get the non-descriptive 'Microsoft SQL Server Error: 18456', here's what I do to determine the actual cause of the issue.

1. On the computer that runs the SQL server, open the **Event Viewer**.
2. Select **Windows Logs** and then **Application**.
3. You should now see an event from the SQL server giving you details about the error message. Here is an example:

   [image]
4. The general description of the event will usually tell you why you get the '18456 error'. In my case it's because the user I'm trying to log in as does not have access to the database or is not allowed to log in to the SQL server in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue happened when the SQL sever and SSMS was preinstalled, so there was no option for me to setup login. Even Windows authentication mode didn't work because the username or login id was not in sql server logins.

**Follow below steps if Windows authentication mode doesn't work.**

**Debug the issue using below steps:**

**1. Check the root SQL server error logs**

[This](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2016/09/08/sql-server-fix-error-18456-severity-14-state-5-login-failed-user/) is why checking the error log is important, or you may waste more time.

Ideally Error log should be in `Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log`

Check [these](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2015/03/24/sql-server-where-is-errorlog-various-ways-to-find-its-location/) steps find error log if still you couldn't find it.

Even if SSMS shows the State of error as 1 , Actual state was 5 inside the error log file, this is weird or maybe for security reasons they show as 1. Below is actual error for log file:

```
Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 5.
Login failed for user 'domain\YourWindowsUser'. Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided. [CLIENT: <local machine>]
```

I asked this error to `ChatGpt`, it gave list of options to do instead of giving actual solution, maybe it was not trained on SO data :). Time is less to do all the steps listed by AI, So I researched and found the answer from SO, human are always wise :)

**2. Reinstall both or create login in single user mode**

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18133336/login-failed-for-user-domain-userid-reason-could-not-find-a-login-matching-t) post, solutions was to Reinstall both or create login in single user mode. Reinstalling and setting up the login is recommended, but I choose the later because already i wasted so much time for this so i needed a quick fix as this server is for development purposes.

**3. Set windows login using Single user mode**

Check [Single user mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/connect-to-sql-server-when-system-administrators-are-locked-out?view=sql-server-ver16&redirectedfrom=MSDN#use-sql-server-configuration-manager-and-management-studio-ssms) official Microsoft document.

Instead of connecting with Object Explorer to create login, I followed 6th point and b, I connected with a Query Window using Windows Authentication. Under 6th point choose any one point, i followed b only.

```
CREATE LOGIN [domain\YourWindowsUser] FROM WINDOWS;
ALTER SERVER ROLE sysadmin ADD MEMBER [domain\YourWindowsUser];
```

Read and follow all the steps listed in the document, finally remove `-m` parameter and restart the sql server service.

This should work, Enjoy, By the way these kind of solutions only human can give and `ChatGpt` or `AI` are helpless without human data. Don't ever think `AI` will replace humans. :)

Hope this helps someone to save time. :)