# Microsoft SQL Server Error: 18456 + windows authentication

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

My PC name is `IBALL1`. I get an error

> Login Failed for user 'iball1\User1'.(Microsoft SQL server, Error: 18456)

I am trying to log in using Windows authentication.

And in SQL Server Configuration Manager > SQl Server Service > SQL Server Logon As Local System.

In error log text file, at `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log`

Log says:

> Login failed for user 'iball1\User1'. Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided. [CLIENT: local machine]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20923015/microsoft-sql-server-error-18456

Comment: there is no solution for me

Comment: Is there a login for User1 ? and what is its privileges ?  Grant Connect, etc .....

Comment: no there is no login for user1

Comment: @ParthSavadiya try the below posted answer most cases it will work

Answer (score 0):

i have also faced same problem then i have followed this intructions

Try this once other wise will look into other solution

**Go to SQL Server Configuration Manager**

**Start->all program->SQL Server 2008 R2->Configuration Tools->SQL Server Configuration Manager**

**Explore "SQL Server Network Configuration" and then select "Protocols For MSSQLSERVER".**

**Check your TCP/IP Protocols in right side pane. If it is disabled then enabled it and Restart the "Sql Server(MSSQLSERVER) service" that available in "SQL Server 2008 R2 services pane".**

Answer (score 0):

Couple of check points:

1) make sure your your sql express services is up and running with name 'IBALL1'
if not try restarting.

2) while connecting give pc name as prefix for server name too .