# Connect to SQL Server with local server user

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database, database-connection, connection-string

I have the following construct:

**srv-mssql1**

- Windows Server 2008
- Microsoft SQL Server
- With a local user: dbuserNT1 (it is added unders Logins as a DB user)

**srv-iisweb1**

- Windows Server 2012
- IIS
- ASP.Net / C# app running

I want to connect to the SQL Server with the user `dbuserNT1` from `srv-iisweb1` (through the ASP.Net app).

How do I have to build my connection string to achieve that?

Please note that `dbuserNT1` is a local user on `srv-mssql1`

So I tought I'd need to use the user `srv-mssql1\dbuserNT1`. But that doesn't work.

Doesn't work trough ssms on my windows 7 machine, but from the `srv-mssql1` also with ssms it works trough windows authentication.

When I try to connect from my Windows 7 machine, ssms throws Error: 18456

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use Data Source= srv-mssql1\SQLSERVERINSTANCE; Initial Catalog=DatabaseName ;User ID=dbuserNT1 ;Password=Password;

Comment: @H.Mikhaeljan Thanks, that was my first guess as well. Tried it again, but I still get the error 18456.

Comment: Maybe this can help you further. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20923015/login-to-microsoft-sql-server-error-18456).  Are you only using the user to authenticate without the password? Maybe try: "Persist Security Info=False;Integrated Security=true; Initial Catalog=Databasename;Server=srv\mssql1\SQLSERVERINSTANCENAME"

Comment: Thank you for the link, I have activated **SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode**
No, I am using the password aswell.
I've just thought about it again - it might be impossible to achieve what I want to do. I'm going with a workaround now.