# Can't access database from code but can using SSMS

Tags: c#, ssms, sql-server-2017

I can log into the db fine from SSMS with

```
localhost\MSSQLSERVER01
```

username: `DOMAIN\user.name` (Windows Authentication)

But when I try connecting from my application I get

```
Error Number:18456,State:1,Class:14
Login failed for user 'DOMAIN\User.Name'.
```

Even though my account can access the db in SSMS and has sysadmin permissions.

Checking the SQL log, I can see this message whenever the login fails:

```
2019-01-22 09:46:42.13 Logon       Login failed for user 'DOMAIN\User.Name'. Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided. [CLIENT: <local machine>]
2019-01-22 09:48:33.74 Logon       Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 5.
```

I tried adding `NT AUTHORIRTY\NETWORK SERVICE` to both `/server/security/logins` as well as `/server/database/security/users` but it made no difference

Why is this happening, or how can I possible debug this when the error message gives me basically no information?

---

The connection string:

```
Server=localhost; Database=dbname; Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;
```

But I also tried

```
Server=localhost\\MSSQLSERVER01; Database=dbname; Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;
```

with the same results

Comment: Can you please show your connection string?

Comment: Does Windows Event Viewer log this? Not sure if it does.

Comment: @Gaurav I added it to my question

Comment: You are missing Integrated Security = true in it please add that.

Answer (score 1):

You connection string should be like this:

> data source=Server\gaurav.goel;database=DBName;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True

Another approach is to use UDL file - create a text file on your machine and change its extension to UDL. Then open this file and try to add your connection into that and check if you can connect or not.

Comment: I'm still seeing the same error after making this change

Comment: ok create a text file on your machine and change its extension to UDL. Then open this file and try to add your connection into that and check if you can connect or not

Comment: Seems there was some confusion with which config file was being called along with a change in environments (meaning my sql instance is called `localhost\mssqlserver01` where it *should* be just `localhost` - sorry about that.. But thank you for the UDL tip that is super useful

Comment: Can you please mark it as answer as it helped you :). I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

An additional thing that might be necessary if it hasn't been done already:

- Right click on the server in SSMS, select the "Properties" option.
- Select the "Connections" tab.
- Check the "Allow remote connections to this server" option.

If you're trying to access it remotely using windows authentication:

- Right click on the server and click Properties
- Go to the Security page
- Under Server authentication choose the SQL Server and Windows
  Authentication mode radio button
- Click OK
- Restart SQL Services

Taken from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23395581/6391339

Comment: Updated my answer