# Can't Login to SQL Server with SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, ssms

So I've been working with SQL Server 2017 Developement for a few hours now.
I set up that I can connect via SQL Server Authentication;

I enabled my SA and I created a new Login.
both were setup properly by standards (Rights to databases etc)

Now I want to use SQL Server Management Studio to login via SQL Server Authentication but I get this error 
(it says sa now but its the same whether it is sa or my created login)

```
TITLE: Connect to Server
------------------------------

Cannot connect to ..

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Login failed for user 'sa'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18456)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=18456&LinkId=20476

------------------------------
BUTTONS:

OK
------------------------------
```

I have "Encrypt connection" & "Trust server certificate" enabled in my options

I have search google for a solution but the only solution to my error is that I need to enable "Trust server certificate" but it doesn't resolve my problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could it be [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20923015/login-to-microsoft-sql-server-error-18456)?

Comment: Right.. Last time I checked i enabled it... somehow it shifted back to Windows Auth Only....

Comment: Have you also restarted the instance after enabling new authentication?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the Server authentication mode, in the service configuration choose the SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode radio button and Restart SQL Services.