# Problem for creating new user in SQL Server Express

Tags: sql-server, express

I have SQL Server Express on Windows 10 Pro:

[image: -]

It works fine.I created databases using the default user (Windows user). I need to specify a user ID and password for other purposes.

I did this

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

but when I try to login using this user id and password, I get this error

[image]

I thought it is very easy to add new user. It seems harder than I thought

---

I also tried to use SA user ID,

I enabled it

and changed the password

Yet I still get this error

[image]

Comment: Do you fully understand the difference between a user and a login? I ask because your question text says you're creating a new user but your screenshots show you're creating a new login and they're not the same thing - login has the password but a login's associated user grants permissions to databases. https://www.top-password.com/blog/difference-between-sql-server-logins-and-database-users/ Might be worth a read

Comment: I just want a user that has a login

Comment: What I'm saying is you'll probably have to create both

Comment: There is new Login and Credentials

Comment: Users have been created in each db, since the login is mapped in User Mapping tab. However, it is strongly recommended to only map the login to the dbs you actually need to access, using the absolutely necessary roles.

Comment: @ManosAnastasiadis I did that, still the same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you might have not enabled SQL Server Authentication too in your server during installation. Setup defaults to Windows Authentication only.
See also [Login to Microsoft SQL Server Error: 18456](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20923015/login-to-microsoft-sql-server-error-18456).